Is it possible for my Worker to retrieve data inside a ViewModel?
I have this situation, basically I have an app that you can save assets with their info and images. But currently the more images you are saving, the longer it takes to save. So I want to change it to call a worker to save the images, so it can continue to save while the user can still use the app.
The problem is, I need to access the data inside the viewModel with the worker, but didn't find any info on how to do it. I wanna know if it's possible or I should do it another way.
I know you can pass data to the worker using a Data.Builder, but what I need to pass is a list of bitmaps, and another list of objects.
I am using Hilt to do the dependency injection for my project, with it I was able to do the DI for another worker that uses some repositories, but I was not able to make a dependency injection to provide the viewModel to the worker I'm trying to create.

"I need to access the data inside the viewModel with the worker" -- there may not be a viewmodel by the time your worker executes. "what I need to pass is a list of bitmaps" -- pass a list of identifiers that can be used to retrieve the bitmaps from a cache.

Accessing a ViewModel directly in a Worker isn't recommended since Workers should be independent of the UI layer. Instead, consider passing the necessary data using Data.Builder and using a repository pattern to handle database interactions efficiently.
